# Object Oriented Programming Benefit

Tags: object-oriented

After so many years I started to study again and finally I arrived at the fateful thesis for the three-year degree.

I've been working for 20 years as a systems engineer and I haven't studied programming since I was a young student. As luck would have it, I was assigned a compendium thesis on object-oriented programming.

Now I wrote a compendium on object oriented programming but the teacher asked me to add a chapter trying to highlight its importance and possible application in a specific area and here I have serious problems since my little experience in development.

Now it is not that I have to write an application I think only highlight a field on which it can be applied this paradigm and its benefits. The problem is that I have no idea where to start.

Do you have any link to get some ideas because at the moment I don't have any and having no experience it's difficult for me to highlight an example field of object oriented programming?

Comment: see [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)

Comment: What exactly does this mean: "highlight a field on which it can be applied this paradigm and its benefits"? What do you mean by field? I presume "this paradigm" means OOP. This sentence is the most critical part of your question and I can't even read it.

Comment: if the code is in a OOP language then its going to be OOP code, difficult to say whether it helped or hindered unless you do the same project in both OOP and a procedural language

Comment: @Ewan that's a dirty marketing lie. I can write procedural code in any language .

Comment: well I guess, but you are unlikely to. and even if your code is procedural then are you using libraries and stuff that's OO? I suppose you might have had a project where you started to do it procedurally but then had to change to OOP, (or vice versa)?

Comment: there are prob load of example of people starting things functionally and then giving up :)

Comment: @Ewan if the library code is code I don't have to support (debug) behind a decent (doesn't leak) abstraction I don't care if it's functional, oop, or procedural. The point is, if you want to see the benefits of OOP you don't just go buy something labeled OOP. You learn to work that way. If you want to prove the benefits you're likely going to need to show how well it reacts to changing requirements.

Comment: Every programmer will eventually run into someone who's convinced that object oriented programming is the only true way. These people can't be reasoned with, so the only to survive is to adapt.

Comment: it would be hard to argue that your procedural code + OOP libraries demonstrated a flaw in the OOP style though. It could always be argued that you benefited from the OOP style of the library. For an academic paper you would want a clear cut example.

Comment: To understand its benefits you must understand what was before OOP. How developing software was before OOP and focus on the weaknesses of the whole SDLC. Put yourself in the shoes of those developers, feel their "pain" at building large systems in a procedural way. Comments here omitting that you have not been asked to argue if OOP is the best or the worst paradigm. Just what It solves and when is adequate.

Answer (score 2):

## GUI programming

Historically, the development of object oriented programming and of graphical user interfaces was closely related. Smalltalk-80 was a hotspot of development of both concepts. Today many GUI frameworks are based on object oriented techniques, even though they may use procedural or functional languages.

Comment: The rise of OO and GUIs together has been purely a matter of coincidence. They both got popular around the same time (around 1990) but neither is strongly linked to the other. There is nothing OO about Win32 and the application of OO in no way depends on any particular domain.

Comment: Actually, Win32 is an example of "poor man's OOP" where the WindowProc is the widget specific message dispatch function. And if you look at the Xerox PARC history (pre 1990) there are indeed strong links where ideas in the areas of programming languages, networking, and user interfaces cross fertilized the fields. You're right in that around 1990 OOP and GUI were not considered closely related, but their development before that time wasn't exactly coincidental.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner, I agree, certainly the GUI aspects of Microsoft Windows are highly object oriented in philosophy. It might even be too much of a concession to say GUI and OOP were considered unrelated in 1990 - look at Visual Basic, which incorporated the Windows GUI, the COM subsystem, and a development environment explicitly oriented around "objects".

Answer (score 0):

Before you can talk benefits you have to explain where the industry was coming from. A benefit is not absolute, it relates to something less beneficial.

Before OO became the norm, **structured programming** was all the rage. Structured programming never went away but as software got bigger and more complex, it was no longer enough to get by with.

Structured programming helps you implement a work flow, a task that has a start and comes to a conclusion, that yields a result. This is good for simple programs, to model algorithms

Most modern software systems do not just comprise one or more of those work flows, they have to deal with a lot of them that are somehow related and dependent on each other and interact with each other. This is where mere structured programming starts to fall short. Its application is limited to flow control logic.

OO solves this by offering a model that allows you to create building blocks that packages a solution to a sub-problem. It does so by combining data and logic into such blocks. You can have the block interact with each other and build big systems with them

So its main benefit is control of complexity. It makes a complex system manageable, both in the development phase and in the maintenance phase.

Fields that benefit the most from OO would be those that are neither purely logic-focussed nor purely data-focussed. An elevator control system for example is mostly flow control logic. Whatever data is involved does not pose a serious problem. An address book access system  on the other hand has rather uninteresting logic, it is all about the data. Systems that need both will benefit the most from OO. I do not think we could pinpoint a particular field or industry that would be particularly suitable for OO, it is more about the type of system that is to be created.

Comment: I'm not sure whether to endorse this analysis. It is precisely because typical OO languages are so poor at expressing necessary structure, that it has become almost synonymous with the extensive presence of 'patterns' and 'frameworks' in even the simplest of programs. Far from "controlling complexity", many have also argued that, in practice at least, the "OO model" has grossly promoted both unnecessary design complexity and computational inefficiency.

Comment: @Steve I do not think patterns and frameworks are OO-bound, they are more likely to be bound to the dominant paradigm which so it happens has been OO for the past 30 years. The market just jumped on it. Management and control always has its price. With OO it is optional, before OO there was just no support for it. OO solved a lot of problems. As the industry evolves, new problems arise and new paradigms emerge which can now be combined as needed. I am not promoting OO as the final solution for everything, I am just puting it in a historical context.

Comment: Indeed. It's worth noting that many of the things OO languages "solve" had solutions in the 'plain' structured era. For example, blocks of code and data were called "programs" rather than "objects" - their external interfaces for passing and returning data, which usually conformed to a loosely-coupled standard, were usually called "files". I think myself that OO languages provide only modest increments in facility, which are quickly exceeded by the perceived need to revert to patterns and verbose ceremonies, custom frameworks, and a myriad of parts with complex interlocking.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing that I can mention regarding the Benefits of OOP, is an approach for managing complexity from a Different "Point of View" compare to other programming approaches.
Let me give you a "Very Bold and Clear" example for the usage of OOP in the Gaming industry.

Think about the objects, characters, enemies, and everything you can see in a game. All of them have some common and some specific characteristics. for example, all of the friends, enemies, and objects have Health as property. they can Attack something or receive damage from other objects/enemies. So we have a bunch of attributes and methods in commons. some of them have the same implementation and some others are overriding it. One of the specific class of enemies have greater attack damage compare to other ones. and there are tons of features that we can mention here. All of these concepts become easy to handle by having Object-Oriented approaches like inheritance, abstraction, interfaces, polymorphism, and so forth. I have prepared an example for what I've explained in the following:

```java
interface Pawn {
int x, y,z;
int health;
int mana;

public void attack(Pawn dest);
public void receiveDmg(int dmg);
public void moveTo(int x, int y, int z);

}

class IronMan implements Pawn{

health = 1500;
int mana = 2000000;
int attackDmg = 50;
int armor = 0.2;
public void attack(Pawn dest){
   dest.receiveDmg(this.attackDmg);
};
public void receiveDmg(int dmg){
 this.health = this.health - ( dmg * (1 - this.armor) );
}
public void moveTo(int x, int y, int z){
// .....
}


}
```

OOP provides a **"Different View"** to solve complex problems. But you should note that OOP is not the Best Answer to all the problems it's why we are speaking on different architecture and principles like functional programming, serverless architecture, and microservices pattern to make sure we have divided our big problems into smaller ones and we would try to solve each one in the best possible way.